# sum elements of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
array = np.array([[[[ 2, -3],[ 3,  2]],[[-4, -1],[-5,  1]],
                [[-7, -5],[-1,  6]],[[-5,  0],[-4,  2]]],
               [[[-1,  4],[ 6,  1]],[[-2, -3],[-5,  5]],
                [[-2, -8],[-1,  7]],[[-1,  8],[-4,  2]]]])
```

[image: array]

If I `sum(array)` then I get the sum of (4x2x2) + (4x2x2).

How can I sum the elements inside of the first arrays, opposite of what sum() function did. Like (2-3) = -1 in the first group, (3+2) = 5 in the second, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Use the axis arg `array.sum(3)`?

Comment: `array.sum(axis=3)` kwarg helps readability!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

summing along the 3rd axis should do what you want:

```
res = np.sum(array, axis=3)
# or:
# res = array.sum(axis=3)
```

which produces

```
[[[ -1   5]
  [ -5  -4]
  [-12   5]
  [ -5  -2]]

 [[  3   7]
  [ -5   0]
  [-10   6]
  [  7  -2]]]
```